# How do i shift my view when ever the keyboard pops up in android irrespective of the device and screen resolution?

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen

Im trying to do something like facebook login.

[image]

[image]

where as whole View shifts up and even "Signup for Facebook" text as well.

**How do i do this ?**

My view code is here, I want to shift this entire relativelayout without keyboard overlapping.

- It has to work fine for all device and screen resolution.

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/fields"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/place"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:background="@color/white">

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/input"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/username"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:hint="User Name"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
      android:maxLength="80" />

  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/password"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_user"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/password"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@id/tc"
      android:layout_alignRight="@id/tc"
      android:hint="Password"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone|actionGo"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:inputType="textPassword" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


  <CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/checkBox"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_password"
  android:text="Keep me logged in"
  android:textSize="14sp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


  <Button
  android:id="@+id/login"
  android:layout_width="165dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:background="@color/red"
  android:text="LOGIN"
  android:textSize="18sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:layout_below="@+id/logged_in_checkBox"
  android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trouble_logging_txt"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/logging_txt"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
  android:text="Trouble logging in ?"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:textSize="18sp"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your activity in manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```